# Enable or Disable Datagridview cell format

Tags: vb.net, winforms, checkbox, datagridview

I have this code that works perfect hidding passwords with "*" but I want disable this function if a checkbox is checked that means show passwords as strings but I don't know how do it in a simple way.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellFormatting
    If (e.ColumnIndex <> -1 AndAlso DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "password") Then
        If (Not e.Value Is Nothing) Then
            e.Value = New String("*", e.Value.ToString().Length)
        End If
    Else
        If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Is your DataGridView data bound ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I thought that if the DataGridView was unbound the actual call value would get replaced by your line

```
e.Value = New String("*", e.Value.ToString().Length)
```

but it's actually not the case. All you seem to be missing is an event handler on your CheckBox to force the DataGridView to refresh, like so:

```
 Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
      DataGridView1.Refresh();
 End Sub
```

Also, you don't really need to do anything when the checkbox is checked, so your cellformatting handler could be as follows:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellFormatting
    If (e.ColumnIndex <> -1 AndAlso DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "password") Then
        If (Not e.Value Is Nothing And Not CheckBox1.Checked) Then
            e.Value = New String("*", e.Value.ToString().Length)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

But now with the checked event handler, the DataGridView will be forced to reformat itself.

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if you are using XAML or not but if you are then you can probably use a TemplateSelector. Build the two templates and then set up a selector class that decides which template to use based on conditions you code in.

Comment: -1 a XAML based answer does not help resolve a winforms problem.

Comment: He didn't specifically state but I see the tag now sorry.